# How do you convert a vector of ints between 1-9 into a "one hot vector" in Octave?

Tags: math, octave

```
y = 3
    6
    2
    7
```

and I want to convert that into a matrix where each row in y becomes a one hot vector:

```
y = 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

I don't want to use any loops. Obviously vectorized is better than even having to do something element-wise. But so far I just have:

```
y./[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
ans =
3.00000   1.50000   1.00000   0.75000   0.60000   0.50000   0.42857   0.37500   0.33333
6.00000   3.00000   2.00000   1.50000   1.20000   1.00000   0.85714   0.75000   0.66667
2.00000   1.00000   0.66667   0.50000   0.40000   0.33333   0.28571   0.25000   0.22222
7.00000   3.50000   2.33333   1.75000   1.40000   1.16667   1.00000   0.87500   0.77778
```

which gives me all the ones but none of the zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter out all the ones:

```
y = [3; 6; 2; 7];
(y./[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]) == 1
```

gives

```
ans =

   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: dude!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @dolphonebubleine Is there some problem? I honestly can't tell what you want to say.

Comment: Nope, that's great. I was really happy how easy that turned out to be.

Comment: It's likely faster to just do `out = y == [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` which is what is shown in the duplicate.

Comment: @Suever Yes, divisions are famous for being *sloooooww*. I mostly wanted to provide this perspective to illustrate how close the OP got. I planned on expanding it, but now that a far superior answer has been linked via the duplicate mechanism, I decided to refrain from it.